# Are there any languages in which the ternary operator can be used to modify code structure?

Tags: ternary-operator, ternary

I am curious to know if there are any languages in which the ternary operator can be used to modify code structure at run time. Such as:

```
boolean bool = true;
// Addition method - can add 2 or 3 integers.
add(5,10 bool ? ) : ,15);
```

I would assume that if this exists anywhere, both the if and else statements of the ternary must be acceptable at compile-time.

Comment: I'd expect Lisp to be able to do it, not this exact syntax obviously.

Answer (score 1):

No, because

1. such a language would be a syntactical nightmare
2. the intended effect can easily be produced by using

   result = bool ? add( 5, 10 ) : add( 5, 10, 15 ) # both expressions evaluated?

   result = add( 5, 10, bool ? 0 : 15 ) # maybe nil, empty, or nix instead of 0

   the standard if of the language